# Density of finite rank operator in compact operators on Hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

> Show the subspace of finite rank operators (defined on a Hilbert space) is dense
>   in the space of all compact operators.

I just started reading about compact operators and I saw this questions. 
So far I learnt any finite rank operator on a Hilbert space is compact, to show it's dense in space of all compact operators, there must exist a sequence of finite rank operator $(T_n)$  such that it converges to compact operator $T$, but I'm not sure how I can construct this sequence, I may need to think about complete orthogonal sequence $\{e_1\:,e_2\dots\} $ of the Hilbert spaces, so I get 
$$T(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\langle T(x),e_i\rangle e_i$$
If I define $T_n(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\langle T(x),e_i\rangle e_i$, this is off course a finite dimensional and compact operator. Can I say it's the sequence that converges to $T$? Or maybe I'm totally wrong, but I appreciate, if you give me some hints about this.

Comment: You can choose the orthonormal basis of eigenvectors of $T$.

Comment: @C.Ding Can I find a sequence of eigenvectors  which forms a basis for the Hilbert space?

Comment: Yes, you can, if $T$ is a normal compact operator.

Comment: @C.Ding  but it's not talking about only normal compact operators!

Comment: But you only have to show normal compact operator is in the space of finite rank operators, since $T$ can be represented as $T=R+iS$ where $R$ and $S$ are hermitian.

Comment: closure of finnite rank operators.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a proof I learned from [some notes of Richard Melrose](https://math.mit.edu/~rbm/18-102-S14/Chapter3.pdf). I just noticed another answer was posted while I was typing. This uses a different characterization of compactness so hopefully it is interesting for that reason.

First, I claim that a set $K\subset H$ of a Hilbert space is compact if and only if it is closed, bounded, and satisfies the equi-small tail condition with respect to any orthonormal basis. This means that given a basis $\{e_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$, for any $\varepsilon>0$ we can choose $N$ large enough such that for any element $u\in H$,
$$\sum_{k>N} |\langle  u , e_k \rangle |^2 < \varepsilon.$$

The main point here is that this condition ensures sequential compactness. The proof is a standard "diagonalization" argument where you choose a bunch of subsequences and take the diagonal. This is done in detail on on page 77 of the notes I linked.

With this lemma in hand, the proof is straightforward. I repeat it from page 80 of those notes. Fix a compact operator $T$. By definition [this is where we use a certain characterization of compactness] the image of the unit ball $T(B(0,1))$ is compact. Then we have the tail condition that, for given $\varepsilon$, there exists $N$ such that

$$\sum_{k>N} |\langle  Tu , e_k \rangle |^2 < \varepsilon.$$
for any $u$ such that $\| u \| < 1$.

We consider the finite rank operators

$$T_nu = \sum_{k\le n} \langle Tu , e_k \rangle e_k.$$

Now note the tail condition is exactly what we need to show $T_n \rightarrow T$ in norm. So we're done.

Answer (score 3):

This answer comes from Murphy's book *$C^*$ algebra and operator theory*(Theorem 2.4.5).

It suffices to show that if $T$ is a hermitian compact operator, then $T\in F(H)^-$(see comments above),where $F(H)$ is the set of all finite rank operators.

Let $E$ be an orthonormal basis of $H$ consisting of eigenvectors of $T$, and let $\varepsilon>0$. We know taht the set $S$ of eigenvalues $\lambda$ of $T$ such that $|\lambda|>\varepsilon$ is finite (Since $\ker(T-\lambda)$ is finite-dimensional for any $\lambda\neq 0$). It is therefore  that the set $S'$ of elements of $E$ corresponding to elements of $S$ is finite.

Now define a finite-rank diagonal operator $u$ on H by setting $u(x) = \lambda x$ if $x\in S'$ and $\lambda$ is the eigenvalue corresponding to $x$, and setting $u(x) = 0 $ if $x \in E \backslash S'$. It is easily checked that $\lVert u — T\rVert \leq \sup_{\lambda\in \sigma(T)\backslash S }|\lambda|\leq\varepsilon$. This shows that $T\in F(H)^-$.

Comment: if we don't talk about complex field, just consider when the compact operator $T=S+i0$, where $S$ is Hermitian. By Hermitian do you mean $\bar{T^*}=T$?Doesn't it mean $T$ is selfadjoint?

Comment: @Parisina here, hermitian = selfadjoint, replace 'hermitian' with 'selfadjoint' as you want.

Answer (score 2):

This is indeed the idea.  My understanding is you need to assume the Hilbert space in question is separable, though I'm not familiar with any counterexamples.

Suppose $\{e_{i}\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a complete orthonormal system.  For each $N \in \mathbb{N}$, consider the operator $T_{N}$ defined by 
$$T_{N}(x) = \sum_{j = 1}^{N} \langle T(x), e_{j} \rangle e_{j}.$$
$T_{N}$ has range contained in $\text{span}\{e_{1},\dots,e_{N}\}$ so it's a finite rank operator.

Recall that $e_{i} \rightharpoonup 0$.  Since $T$ is compact, it follows that $T(e_{i}) \to 0$ in norm.

We claim $\lim_{n \to \infty} \|T_{n} - T\| = 0$.  Pick $\epsilon > 0$.  By the preceding remark, we can find $\mathcal{I} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $$\|T(e_{i})\|^{2} < \epsilon^{2}$$
if $i \geq \mathcal{I}$.  Moreover, since $\{1,2,\dots,\mathcal{I} - 1\}$ is finite, we can find $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that 
$$\sum_{j = n + 1}^{\infty} |\langle T(e_{i}), e_{j} \rangle|^{2} < \epsilon^{2}$$
if $i \in \{1,2,\dots,\mathcal{I}\}$ and $n \geq N$.

Now suppose $x$ is any vector in the Hilbert space.  If $n \geq N$, then
\begin{align*}
\|(T - T_{n})(x)\|^{2} &= \sum_{j = n + 1}^{\infty} |\langle T(x), e_{j} \rangle|^{2}  \\
&= \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} |\langle x, e_{i} \rangle|^{2} \left(\sum_{j = n + 1}^{\infty} |\langle T(e_{i}),e_{j}\rangle|^{2}\right) \\
&\leq \sum_{i = 1}^{\mathcal{I} - 1} |\langle x,e_{i} \rangle|^{2} \left(\sum_{j = n + 1}^{\infty} |\langle T(e_{i}),e_{j} \rangle|^{2}\right) + \sum_{i = \mathcal{I}}^{\infty} |\langle x,e_{i} \rangle|^{2} \|T(e_{i})\|^{2} \\
&\leq \epsilon^{2} \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} |\langle x,e_{i} \rangle|^{2}
\end{align*}
by the choice of $\mathcal{I}$ and $N$.  From this, we deduce that $\|T - T_{n}\| \leq \epsilon$.  Since $\epsilon$ was chosen arbitrarily, we conclude $\lim_{n \to \infty} \|T - T_{n}\| = 0$.

Comment: No, there is no need to assume $H$ is separable.

Comment: your second inequality is far away from being correct.

Answer (score 2):

We can reduce to the separable case since $T\in \mathcal{L}_c(X)$ compact implies that $X = Ker(T)\oplus \overline{Ran(T)}$ and $\overline{Ran(T)}$ is separable since $T$ is compact.

Fix $\{e_k\}_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ Hilbert basis of $X$, let  $P_n $ be the metric projector onto $Span(e_1,\dots, e_n)$, i.e. $P_n(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n \langle x, e_k\rangle e_k$.  I say that $P_n\circ T\to T$ in operator norm.
Indeed
$$||P_n\circ T - T||_{\infty, B_X} = ||P_n - I||_{\infty, \overline{T(B_X)}} \to 0$$
where the last convergence is to be intended as strong operator convergence (we have this convergence since $\{e_k\}_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ is an Hilbert basis). But since $\{P_n - I\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is an equicontinuos family and $\overline{T(B_X)}$ is compact, strong operator convergence implies norm convengence. Obviously the $P_n\circ T$ are finite rank operators so we are done.